# Kafka High Level Consumer shuts down thread

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I am using a high level consumer as described at: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

I am noticing that my consumer does not run forever and ends after some time. At the zookeeper side, I see the following:

> INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x144a4854325004d
>   (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:59899 which had
>   sessionid 0x144a4854325004d (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)

I am using default configurations. How do I make my consumer listen forever?

Comment: did you try changing the `zookeeper.session.timeout.ms` , `zookeeper.sync.time.ms` params to see if there is any effect on this .. and also it would be useful to see some more stacktrace as well as the consumer code you are running with.

Comment: Have you solved yet.. I am also facing same problem. :(

Comment: There's not enough info here to figure out what's going on. Zookeeper timeouts could be a problem. Maybe you're getting stuck in a rebalance loop?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try to run the ConsoleConsumer.

Comment: Console consumer runs fine. I want to do some further processing of messages - so have to do it through code. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you processing producer or consumer side?  Can be do-able with console consumer.

Comment: Consumer side. I figured it would be just easier using the java code. The wiki says "The interesting part here is the while (it.hasNext()) section. Basically this code reads from Kafka until you stop it." I'm not sure if this is accurate.

Comment: You could just re-write ConsoleConsumer to plug into whatever you want to do to change the messages.  Another possibility is that the message change itself is the cause of your disconnecting--might be worth checking up on that.

Comment: I am just printing out the messages for now, so that's not an issue. I wonder if there is a consumer configuration that's causing this issue. I am getting false for hasNext() of the ConsumerIterator which means the connector is shutdown - not sure what could be the cause of this.

Comment: does it shut down when it's done with receiving all the messages?

Comment: @La-comadreja For the consumer, there is no such thing as "all the messages". It's a stream, so there is no way for the consumer to know a priori how many messages are going to be sent. I have used the same code and it blocks at the `hasNext()` call until a new message is received. @user3399291, please post more of the log messages, and the surrounding code. The more information that is available, the easier it is to spot a problem.

Comment: "all the messages" meaning all the messages that have been sent out up to that point.